# Why doesn't jQuery click function work?

Tags: jquery

```
  <script>
 $("#btn1").click(function() {
     $("#logpop").hide("slow");
  });

  </script>
<body>

<div id="logpop">
    <div class="logpop_box">
    <div class="form">
    <input class="input_box" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Woosuk"/>                                  <br/><br/>
    <input class="input_box" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="******"/>  <br/>
    <button id="btn1">Login</button>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make div disappear when i click the button.
but It dose not disappear.
Any thought

Comment: Place your script somewhere after the `btn1` element, yet still within the `<body></body>`, and it will work. Some people like to put their scripts just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 6):

Your JavaScript needs to be in a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
     $("#logpop").hide("slow");
  });
});
```

Currently your click handler is executing before the DOM has been created, thus it can't be attached.

Answer (score 3):

You should register your click handler inside a document-ready block:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(...);
});
```

Your script is running before the element exists, and so no click handler is registered.

Answer (score 2):

Further to what the other answers said, you can't select an element that has not yet been parsed, given that the browser executes inline JavaScript in the order in which it appears while it parses the source document - so at the point your code runs no elements have been parsed. There are two ways to get around this:

1. Put your code in a `$(document).ready()` handler (or use an old-school `onload` event handler).
2. Move your script block to anywhere *after* the element(s) it tries to reference. Most people find script blocks in the middle of the document messy, so (unless absolutely necessary) I'd suggest putting it at the end, right before the closing `</body>` tag.